# Sharing `Static` Methods Between Classes in a Single File in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, objective-c++

I am baffled by a `static` method whose definition apparently lives in one class, but whose declaration is shared between several classes **in the same file.**  **Can it be shared between files somehow?**

**The Details**

I'm trying to divide a `.mm` file into several files (one per class). All of the source code is from [Pete Goodliffe's CoreMIDI Example](http://gitorious.org/midimonitor/midimonitor).

I took the [PGMidi class from here](http://gitorious.org/midimonitor/midimonitor/blobs/master/Sources/MIDI/PGMidi.mm) and busted it up into separate interfaces and classes. Everything compiles perfectly except for one method marked `static`, which needs to be in two places at once (it's "used but never defined" in PGMidi). The method is "used" in this line outside of any class implementation:

```
static void PGMIDIReadProc(const MIDIPacketList *pktlist, void *readProcRefCon, void *srcConnRefCon);
```

which is apparently shared by all classes **in the same file** (what?). It's mentioned in two classes.

1) In `PGMidi`, where it's used (perhaps pointing to `PGMidiSource`

```
s = MIDIInputPortCreate(client, (CFStringRef)@"MidiMonitor Input Port", PGMIDIReadProc, self, &inputPort);
```

2) In `PGMidiSource`, where the method body is defined

```
static
void PGMIDIReadProc(const MIDIPacketList *pktlist, void *readProcRefCon, void *srcConnRefCon)      
{
   PGMidiSource *self = (PGMidiSource*)srcConnRefCon;
   [self midiRead:pktlist];
}
```

The problem is that the `self` referred to in the method body makes no sense in `PGMidi` (no `midiRead` method)...

What is this `static` method? How I can get it to work between two files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a function, the `static` keyword roughly means "only visible and usable from within this file". Since it was defined in `PGMidiSource.mm`, you cannot call it from `PGMidi.mm`. Luckily, this is fairly easy to fix.

1. Declare the function prototype in `PGMidiSource.h`, like this:

   `void PGMIDIReadProc(const MIDIPacketList *pktlist, void *readProcRefCon, void *srcConnRefCon);`
2. Remove the `static` keyword in `PGMidiSource.mm`, since it needs to be usable from outside that file.

Note that this is not a "method"; it is a C function. As such, it belongs to no class, is not tied to any instance, has no access to any instance variables, etc. Any context that it needs must be passed in as a parameter. Hence, while this function uses a variable called "self", it's actually just a local alias for one of the parameters that was passed in.

Comment: @Yar:  that was probably a name mangling issue.  C++ adds stuff to function names to encode the parameter types so that functions can be overloaded.

Answer (score 3):

The static function is just a normal C function.  The 'static' means it can only be accessed from within the same file.  So you need to either:

- Redefined it for every file you want use it from, typically by putting the entire static function definition in a header and include the header in every file you want to use it, or
- Make it a non-static function and put the function prototype in a header, then include the header in every file you want to use it from.

Comment: Great +1 [must break minimum-word limit on comments, sorry]

Answer (score 1):

The reason that it looks like that "method" is shared between multiple classes is because it's not technically a method.  Instead, that's a C function.  You can add C to Objective C in that manner, and that particular function can be invoked from multiple files, though it's a good practice to provide a "prototype" in a header file for the files that don't have the actual function implemented within them.  (Or it was the last time I wrote in C.  It's been a while.)

If you don't provide the prototype in the other files, C will let you go merrily on your way (though the compiler will probably say it doesn't know anything about that function in a warning.)  But the linker will resolve it, and assuming it's coded correctly, it should work.